# jQuery change z-index with data-*

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have divs that all occupy the same space, and I want to set up jQuery that has one div come on top of the other as different tabs are clicked. I assume this has to be done by changing the z-index attribute using a data-* attribute that connects the tab to the div.

```
    /*The tabs to be clicked*/

    <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab" data-tabcontainer-id="websites" style="background-color:#1aa3ff;">Websites</li>
    <li class="tab" data-tabcontainer-id="sitemaps">Sitemaps</li>
    <li class="tab" data-tabcontainer-id="pages">Pages</li>
    </ul>

    /*The divs that need to come on top of each other*/

    <div id="websites" class="tabcontainer">Websites</div>
    <div id="sitemaps" class="tabcontainer">Sitemaps</div>
    <div id="pages" class="tabcontainer">Pages</div>
```

Comment: no, to change the z-index **style** you use the elements **style** attribute - specifically `style.zIndex`

Comment: or you can toggle class with z index specified

Comment: better go with toggle display:block/none

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DEMO**

http://plnkr.co/edit/aNomjINfbYYrRUhMj63A?p=preview

This is how you can change the `z-index` property using the data attribute.

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tab').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).data('tabcontainer-id');
    $('.tabcontainer').css('z-index', '0'); //resets z-index to 0 for all other
    $('.tabcontainer#'+target).css('z-index', '1'); //sets z-index for current target to 1
  })  
});
```

I wrote the answer just to meet what you were asking. But reading your question I think you should have a look at the tabs feature by jQuery UI. May be it will help.

https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I appreciate the help and the recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

better go with toggle display:block/none

```
$('.tabcontainer').not('.tabcontainer:first').hide();
$('.tab').click(function(){
      //toggle active class on tabs
      $('.tab').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      //show corresponding tab container
      var id = '#'+$(this).attr('data-tabcontainer-id');
      $('.tabcontainer').hide();//here you can go with another class like above that will toggle between block and none
      $(id).show();
});
```

demo:http://plnkr.co/edit/gPIwv80vUIUTQ46Bderj?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

madalin ivascu's answer is quite right according to me.

May be bit off the topic, but you can use Jquery UI for the tabs. Easy to implement and work with.
You don't need to worry about managing the z-index in this case. But it might not be appropriate for your case.

```
<div id="tabs">
     <ul >
        <li><a href="#websites" style="background-color:#1aa3ff;">Websites</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sitemaps">Sitemaps</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pages">Pages</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="websites" class="tabcontainer">Websites</div>
    <div id="sitemaps" class="tabcontainer">Sitemaps</div>
    <div id="pages" class="tabcontainer">Pages</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/uxwyj4d4/

Answer (score 0):

Example for showing tabs using vanilla js, no jQuery is required.
This example use only display instead of z-index.

```js
// get tabs
var targets = {
websites: document.getElementById('websites'),
sitemaps: document.getElementById('sitemaps'),
pages: document.getElementById('pages')
  },
  show = function(target) {
hideAll();
targets[target.dataset.tabcontainerId].style.display = '';
  },
  hideAll = function() {
  // hide all tabs
Object.keys(targets).forEach(function(key) {
  targets[key].style.display = 'none';
});
  };
// when click on link show tab
document.getElementById('w').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  show(event.target);
});
document.getElementById('s').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  show(event.target);
});
document.getElementById('p').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  show(event.target);
});
```

```css
#websites,
#sitemaps,
#pages {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#websites {
  background-color: red;
}

#sitemaps {
  background-color: blue;
}

#pages {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li id="w" class="tab" data-tabcontainer-id="websites" style="background-color:#1aa3ff;">Websites</li>
  <li id="s" class="tab" data-tabcontainer-id="sitemaps">Sitemaps</li>
  <li id="p" class="tab" data-tabcontainer-id="pages">Pages</li>
</ul>



<div id="websites" class="tabcontainer">Websites</div>
<div id="sitemaps" class="tabcontainer">Sitemaps</div>
<div id="pages" class="tabcontainer">Pages</div>
```